# Hack the in operator to return non booleans

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to know if there is a not too complicated way to have `x in y` returns arbitrary value (other than boolean) in python 2.7.

`__contains__` result seems to get cast to boolean and I don't find an obvious way to use the `__iter__` or `__getitem__` either. This could be done by modifying the CPython but I'd like to stay out of it if possible; `y` can be as complicated as you want.

I know this is a bad practice, non pythonic, what I want to do with it can be done differently, it might be dangerous ... This is not the point of this question, thank you.

Comment: Why do you need `in` to return something else?

Comment: I actually want 'y' to contains thing depending on some condition so `x in y` could for instance return "with probability p" or "if λ > 1". I know I could write my own modified 'in' and even mimic its behavior using the [infix trick](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/384122-infix-operators) but, for the challenge and the fun of it, I'd like to know if I could actually use the in operator.

Comment: You can't. The behaviour is [hardcoded](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d641c096b1f5/Objects/typeobject.c#l5080) to return a bool.

Comment: Giving a look at PyObject_IsTrue convince me too that this path is blocked. This is a bit sad, or maybe good for our sanity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can return whatever you want from `__contains__`. However, the `in` operator always turns that value into a boolean value; this is [hardcoded to return a boolean value](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d641c096b1f5/Objects/typeobject.c#l5080):

```
result = PyObject_IsTrue(res);
```

where [`PyObject_IsTrue()`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#PyObject_IsTrue) produces a boolean the same way the [`bool()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool) does.

Use a different operator in this case; perhaps override `__rshift__` to overload the `>>` operator:

```
x >> y
```

or just use a dedicated method:

```
y.contains_with_probability(x)
```

Answer (score -2):

I hope this will help you:

```
x=2
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
print x if x in y else False
```

Comment: How does this help the OP change how `__contains__` behaves?

Comment: Actually behave like this: __contains__(self, item)
__contains__ defines behavior for membership tests using in and not in. Why isn't this part of a sequence protocol, you ask? Because when __contains__ isn't defined, Python just iterates over the sequence and returns True if it comes across the item it's looking for. [Source: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html]

Comment: Unfortunately in your example the `if x in y` still returns a boolean,  yes the `x if ... else ...` wrapper allow to return arbitrary values but I'd like that do be done by the `in` operator itself.